# React renders only one item from list downloaded from firebase

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to show a list of users, I get from Firebase Realtime Database. On the logs I get them all! But on the screen, only the first one appears. If I put as a dependency `users` I get an infinite loop on the logs but still one item on the screen. `useCallback` didn't help either. If I fill in the inputs on the screen, thus trigger a re-render, then I get all the users. Why doesn't it get them all on the first place? Could it be something with Typescript?

Thanks!

```js
...
const [users, setUsers] = useState<any[]>([]);
const [usersRef] = useState<any>(firebase.database().ref().child('users'));

...
const getUsers: () => void = useCallback(() => {
    const loadedUsers: any[] = []
    usersRef.on('child_added', (snap: any) => {
      loadedUsers.push(snap.val())
      setUsers(loadedUsers)
      console.log('loadedUsers', loadedUsers);
    })
  }, [setUsers, usersRef])

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
    return () => usersRef.off()
  }, [usersRef, getUsers])


  const displayUsers = (users: any) => {
    console.log(users);
    return users.length > 0 && users.map((user: any) =>
      <li key={user.id}>
        {user.email}
      </li>
    )
  }
...

  <ul>
    {displayUsers(users)}
  </ul>
```

So, thanks to @Renaud Tarnec, it turned out to be a problem with the firebase listener. I had to listen on `value` change instead of `child_added`. Below is the new version. I don't really like the way `displayUsers` turned out to be, but it works. If any has any suggestions, I would be happy to see.

Thanks again!

```js
  const getUsers: () => void = useCallback(() => {
    const loadedUsers: any[] = []
    usersRef.on('value', (snap: any) => {
      loadedUsers.push(snap.val())
      setUsers(loadedUsers)
      console.log('loadedUsers', loadedUsers);
    })
  }, [setUsers, usersRef])
...


const displayUsers = (users: any) => {
    console.log(users);
    return users.length > 0 && users.map((userObj: any) => {
      const users = []
      for (const key in userObj) {
        users.push(userObj[key])
      }
      return users.map((user: any) =>
        <li key={user.id}>
          {user.email}
        </li>
      )
    }
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your problem, this is because you use the `child_added` event instead of the `value` one. See the difference between the two in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on):

> **value event**
>
> This event will trigger once with the initial data stored at this
> location, and then trigger again each time the data changes. The
> DataSnapshot passed to the callback will be for the location at which
> `on()` was called..
>
> **child_added event**
>
> This event will be triggered once for each initial child at this
> location, and it will be triggered again every time a new child is
> added. The DataSnapshot passed into the callback will *reflect the data
> for the relevant child*.

In summary, with the `value` event you get all the data at this location, while with the `child_added` event you get the data of the child.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'll set the finished code above. And I'll have a better look in the docs!